# Should I remove `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` from docker-compose.yml after `docker compose up`?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I follow instructions from https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres to deploy PostgreSQL database server.

I notice this warning:

> Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.

Also if I `docker exec -it pgdb env`, then I can see: `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin
HOSTNAME=ab39b8a07972
TERM=xterm
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
PGTZ=Europe/Zaporozhye
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=****
GOSU_VERSION=1.14
LANG=en_US.utf8
PG_MAJOR=15
PG_VERSION=15.0-1.pgdg110+1
HOME=/root
```

It seems not so secure, when allowed to see password for database root administrator.

Should I remove `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` at all from `docker-compose.yml` after first deployment? If yes, which other variables I should remove also?

Comment: You can if you want, but since running that `docker exec` command already requires privileged access to your machine, it seems like a rather ineffective hardening attempt, more likely to inconvenience yourself than any bad guys.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'm under the impression that it's just a default password to get the system set up and running and you're actually supposed to change it afterwards.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: Probably yes, but I did no see any recommendations to do that. It is supposed that your docker-compose.yml is at secure place (but I could be wrong).